# best way to contact classes not in testRunner class and with Conditions

Tags: java, selenium

I have two packages, 1 contains the testRunner that extends baseTest
2 contains baseTest and class that extends baseTest for each page,
I want to test if some article appears in one of the pages, if not I should return to the main page of the site and select the main article.
I have to try catch at the specific article pages that I'm looking for so in case the article isn't found, the driver will return to the main page, the problem is that all these methods runs from the testRunner and there I don't have any try catch cause it's not methodology to write it over there, so how I can go over these issue without adding the try catch at the testRunner?
I'm using junit

I have tried already to add the try catch to the article page but it seems that there is no way of running from adding the try catch to the @test itself

methood of the find article:

```
 public void findArticle()  {
 try {
 waitUntilClickable(benksyArticle);
 clickOnArticle();
   } catch (articleIsntFound e) {
 returnToMainPage(ReturnURL);
   } catch (Exception e) {
 returnToMainPage(ReturnURL);   
   }
 }
```

testRunner:

```
 public void testMethoods() {
 //navigate to culture and select specific article
 main.getPage(URL);
 mainCulturePage.findArticle();

  //if article isn't found so go back to main page and select the main 
article
  mainArticle.clickOnMainArticle();
  mainArticle.titleCheck();
  mainArticle.gettags();

}
```

I expected to avoid the try catch at the testRunner

Answer (score 0):

you can use method for checking is element present:

```
  public boolean isElementPresent(element) {
        return driver.findElements(element).size() > 0;
    }
```

After it your example can looks like:

```
 public void findArticle()  {
        waitUntilClickable(benksyArticle);
        isElementPresent(benksyArticle)? clickOnArticle() : returnToMainPage(ReturnURL);
    }
```